# Passing form values with RESTful routing in Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, rest, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have setup nested RESTful resource routes like so:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'opening-hours'), function(){
    Route::resource('library', 'LibraryController');
    Route::resource('library.interval', 'LibraryIntervalController');
});
```

I have a blade form which has a select dropdown with options populated from the db, like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'opening-hours.library.show', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
    <legend>Select a library to edit</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Please select a library to modify its opening hours:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="id" required>
        @foreach ($library_options as $id => $name)
          <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The form submits to the named route:

opening-hours.library.show

The routing itself works but I have a couple of questions about the logistics (I'm a little confused about how to use the routing):

- I can get the form to submit to the correct route if I make it a
  'GET' request (GET/HEAD opening-hours/library/{library} =>
  opening-hours.library.show), as the corresponding POST route does not
  exist
- how do I pass the user-selected $id to the controller show($id)
  method?
- when I submit the form, it goes to the URI
  "../opening-hours/library/%7Blibrary%7D?id=3". So if the user selects
  the library with id=3, how do I make the URI "../opening-hours/library/3"?

Here is my Library controller show method:

```
/**
 * Display the specifed library.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
    return "This is a library with id: " . $id . "!";
}
```

When I submit the form, the following is displayed:

This is a library with id: {library}!

Of course, I'd want it to display:

This is a library with id: 3!

I'm obviously not understanding something critical about how REST or Laravel or both work here. Any pointers would be very much appreciated, I've spent a day knocking about with this!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing out the problem seemed to help me come up with the solution. It seemed silly to use a form to send a 'GET' request, so I thought (bing!) why not just construct the URIs as anchor tag href attributes. So instead of using a form, I did:

```
@foreach( $library_options as $id => $name )    
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::to('opening-hours/library/' . $id) }}">Edit {{ $name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

That solved the issue of dodgy URIs and also the id was directly available from the RESTful controller method like so:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return "This is a library with id: " . $id . "!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$id = Input::get('id');
```

[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

I would also recommend using the provided helpers for forms:

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'));
```

[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

Comment: thanks for that - Input::get('id') did allow me to access the $id variable but didn't solve the issue of the generated URIs. I solved my problem by using anchors instead of a form